# TwiML Conference Calling does not take inbound caller to Voicemail when client does not pick up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am building my app with the same flow as the one found here with warm transfers:

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/warm-transfer-rails

I have incoming calls, which must be converted to conferences to allow warm transfers.

```
  # Starting point for inbound/outbound calls
  def connect_call
    phone_call = phone_call_from_twilio # gets phone call record based off callSID

    # this method calls the support agent,who receives the phone call on their browser
    phone_call.create_call(connect_conference_participant_url)

    # generate TWIML to tell twiml how to respond to call
    render xml: generate_connect_conference(phone_call, true, true)
  end

  # this API endpoint is accessed by Twilio
  def conference_wait
    twiml = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new do |r|
      r.play(url: '/audio/welcome-message.mp3')
    end.to_s

    render xml: twiml
  end

  # function to generate TWIML to tell twiml how to respond to call.
  def generate_connect_conference(phone_call, start_on_enter, end_on_exit)
    r = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
    d = Twilio::TwiML::Dial.new(timeout: 200)
    d.conference(phone_call.call_sid,
      start_conference_on_enter: start_on_enter,
      wait_url: conference_wait_url,
      # participant_label: phone_call.from_wp? ? phone_call.from_participant_label : phone_call.to_participant_label,
      status_callback_method: 'POST',
      status_callback_event: 'start join end leave',
      status_callback: status_callback_url,
      record: 'record-from-start',
      recording_status_callback: voice_recording_callback_url,
      recording_status_callback_method: 'POST',
      end_conference_on_exit: end_on_exit,
    )
    r.append(d)
    r.to_s
  end

...

in phone_call.rb

  def create_call(wait_url)
    to_string = from_wp? ? to : "client:support_agent?patientName=#{ patient&.name }&fromPhoneNumber=#{ from }&callSid=#{ call_sid }&conferenceSid=#{ conference_sid }"

     PhoneCall.twilio_client.calls.create(
       from: from,
       to: to_string,
       url: "#{ ENV['URL'] }#{ wait_url }"
     )
  end
```

This code puts the inbound call into a conference call, also calls a support agent, which is on an app using the Twilio JS SDK.

However, when the support agent does not accept the call, the problem is the caller is stuck waiting forever. How do I make sure that the caller goes to voicemail after a certain time out period?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options here.

Firstly, you could start a scheduled job within your application. You can schedule this job for the maximum time you want the user to wait for, and when the job is triggered, it updates the call and sends the caller to voicemail. If, however, the agent answers the call, then you can cancel the job and the call goes on as planned.

Alternatively, rather than having the user wait in the conference call, you could add them to a queue with the [`<Enqueue>` TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue). Then, when the agent answers the phone, you update the call, moving them out of the queue and into the conference. The benefit of the queue is that [requests to the `waitUrl`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue#attributes-waitUrl) come with additional parameters, including `QueueTime`, the time in seconds that the caller has been waiting. You could use recurring calls to the `waitUrl` to judge how long the caller has been waiting and move the call onto voicemail if it passes your threshold.